# Changing a points actual size globally?

Tags: ios, swift, scale

Is there a way to globally change the default scale of an iOS app? With "scale" I mean the physical size the points represent if that makes sense. I don't want to apply any transforms or scaling to a single view, I want it to be applied globally or per-screen basis.

I have tried to modify the `nativeScale` and `scale` properties of UIView but it doesn't seem to be possible.

### Example

**Default behaviour**

By default, a square with width 100 vs width 200 is rendered as follows:

[image]
[image]

**Goal**

When specifying width 100, I want the square to be rendered with twice the size (points):

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you willing to achieve that? Isn't just easier to set width to 200? What is the purpose?

Comment: Yeah... why? Maybe you are looking for constraints?

Comment: The root issue is scaling differences between platforms in a cross-platform app (iOS, tvOS, Android, Android TV). To be able to share code every size needs to be multiplied on tvOS compared to iOS. That is not the case on Android TV compared to Android. 

It is related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745363/how-do-i-handle-scaling-issues-in-a-react-native-app-between-tvos-and-android-tv

Comment: @aheze not sure how constraints would help here, wouldn't the width be changed then?

Comment: For cross-platform apps I think that it is better to take an approach with the Screen Size. In a variable you can store the screen height and width. And then work with screen percentages. For example, if you want a button to occupy 10% of the screen height you set it's height to 0.1*ScreenHeight.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely an option! If this could be solved in another way, it would simplify a lot in this particular situation though.

Comment: With auto-layout you can set relative constraints, f.e. button width equal to half parent view width.

Comment: use transform property of UIVIew

Comment: @paiv i need to be able to set a fixed number of points in this case.

Comment: @ChanOnly123 is there a way to use a transform on an entire screen instead of a single screen?

Comment: Using transform...? That sounds very risky. @HenningHall, you really should use constraints.

Comment: it's really simple to achieve yours with a global constant. But think about how to use contraints to match different screen's size is better than scale up everything.

Comment: @HenningHall if you've found my answer unsatisfactory please express your concerns  in the answer's comments and I will do my best to address them.

Comment: So you ask a question that is very likely impossible, start a bounty and you ignore the people that have tried to help you without any explanation of why the proposed solutions don't work for you. I'll be sure to not waste my time with any of your questions again.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I didn't consider it to be "very likely impossible" since it is possible on Android (through the densityDpi config). My iOS skills are limited why asking this question seemed appropriate to me. Thanks for your answer, as you expected yourself, the answer didn't solve it for me, but I should definitely got back to you sooner, I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

"By default, a square with width 100 vs width 200 is rendered as follows:"

I don't think it will work on as you give input but it will work on multiplier of your screen bounds. i am not able to make comment so i share as answer.

take a look here where i share a simple project to understand how it will work.

https://github.com/jatinfl15/ResizeScreenWise

[image]

here i assign innerview aspect to `width` of screen. innerview multiplier assign `0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to change CG to use *Pixel Coordinates* instead of *Point Coordinates*. There are a number of scaling and rasterization options for `CALayer` but I do not think they will do what you want.

Here is a programmatic solution that uses an extension so you can do a CGRect() style:

```
let rectInPixels = CGRect(pointsX: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

Results:

```
rectInPixels: (100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0)
```

Only difference is you use "pointsX:" instead of "x:" when creating a rect. Of course, you can use whatever argument name that makes most sense to you.

Or convert a rect from points to pixels:

```
//Create a rect using Point coordinates
let rectInPoints = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)

//Convert from Points to Pixel coordinates
let rectInPixels = rectInPoints.pixelCoords
```

Results:

```
rectInPixels: (100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0)
```

Of course you can make a similar extension for `CGPoint` or any other datatype.

Extension:

```
public extension CGRect {
    init(fromPointCoords pointRect: CGRect) {
        let res = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
        self.init(x: pointRect.origin.x * res, y: pointRect.origin.y * res, width: pointRect.size.width * res, height: pointRect.size.height * res)
    }

    init(pointsX x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        let rectPixels = CGRect(fromPointCoords: CGRect(x, y, width, height))
        self.init(origin: rectPixels.origin, size: rectPixels.size)
    }

    var pixelCoords:CGRect {
        get {
            return CGRect(fromPointCoords: self)
        }
        set(newValue) {}
    }

}
```